# Free binary file editor that shows byte values in binary and/or decimal

Tags: windows, gratis, educational, hex-viewer

I would like to find a "hex" editor that can show the value of each byte in binary or decimal.

This would be useful in my freshman class where students have not yet learned the binary or hexadecimal number systems (in great detail) and are learning to write files in a binary format.

I have considered HxD, HexEdit, and Universal Viewer as recommended in [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/what-is-a-good-hex-viewer-for-windows/2752#2752), but none of these offers this feature (that I could find). HxD and HexEdit offer binary **indexes**, but not binary **values** of bytes.

Currently, the hex-editors like HxD and HexEdit are not much more useful than notepad to my students because they cannot read the hexadecimal values.

Comment: Not quite what you want, and not free, but I am really impressed by [010 editor](https://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/) and am now Googling for alternatives.

Comment: Have you considered forking a FOSS hex editor to add a binary display? It shouldn't be too much work. Or suggest such a feature to the authors?

Comment: I think I will suggest my students write one from scratch :-)

Comment: If they public domain it, please come back & place a link here

Comment: For what it's worth, HxD (and probably others) let you see one byte at a time in binary and decimal (8-bit integer) in a separate real-time pane (the so-called "Data inspector"). Obviously, this is tedious if you need to see a whole screen worth of binary or decimal values, but it's something.

Comment: Also, I'm curious what you are teaching, where it makes more sense to learn to "write files in a binary format" *without* understanding hexadecimal, than to learn hexadecimal first or concurrently. At some point, they have to learn hexadecimal anyway, right?

Comment: We introduce binary and decimal numbers in depth in the fall of our students' sophomore year.  But we introduce file I/O in the winter of their freshman year. So although they have some concept of a binary number, they aren't very solid on it yet.

Comment: @JohnY Could you point me to how to use the Data Inspector? I can't find it or documentation about it.

Comment: Re: Data Inspector - It's pretty obvious and always turned on by default. It's a new feature in version 2.0.0.0. Hard to miss, but if it's somehow not open already, it's in View > Toolbars.

Comment: Re: Binary file I/O - I don't mean to challenge your curriculum, but it seems to me that if you want to insist on delaying proper treatment of binary and hexadecimal, then you could just as easily delay *binary* file I/O and only do text-based file I/O until they are comfortable with hex.

Comment: @JohnY It is challenging to get things in order!  I'll ask my colleagues about it at some point. And I love the new data inspector! It looks like it just came out 16 July  2018, which is probably why I missed it. Would you like to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest update of [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) was released in July 2018 and among its new features is the Data Inspector.

This is a display pane which is open by default and shows various interpretations of the data at the cursor, including binary. As you move the cursor, this display updates automatically. It's not exactly what you asked for, since you can only see the one byte at a time in this view, but it still could be useful.

[image: HxD 2.0 screenshot]